# pure C++ design pattern non-blocking for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, nonblocking

I tried to read about my problem but can't even find the right words to google it.

Lets say I have a function like this in pure C++ (will run on an ESP32, no threads):

```cpp
void do_something_for_a_long_time(vector a) {
  for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < 1000; j++) {
      if(a.start == a.end) {
        //go deeper
        do_something_for_a_long_time(a[1]);
      } else {
        //end of recursion
        //do something with vector
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is a little bit more complex but the main task is like the code above.
I calculate a few things in a loop and with recursion. I have to use pure C++ without threads as it will run on Arduino.

What would be a good design pattern to solve something like this to be able to get a non-blocking calculation:

```cpp
loop() {
  //call this often
  do_something_non_blocking(...);
  //other stuff
}
```

The thing I mean is that I would like to do one next step if the non-blocking function is called and would call the function very, very often instead of call it once and get the result (and block everything).
I could create some complex state machine but would like to find a general clean solution. It is partly to get better with the design if problems like this come up.

Ideas:

- split for loops in

  - init
  - body
  - exit
- write a macro library to encapsulate code in a state machine

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `fork` or an equivalent.

Comment: `if(a.start == a.end) { do_something_for_a_long_time(a[1]);` makes no sense. Making your code simpler for the sake of a minimal example is good, but this is not "minimal", it just makes no sense

Comment: you dont need a sophisticated state machine, you only need to encapsualte it in a class that has a `perform_one_step` method

Comment: What's the meaning of the term  *"blocking"* in this context? **Blocking** normally means waiting for another **concurrent** piece of code to reach a certain point.

Comment: It's something aking to problems that existed in 80s and early 90s on single-threaded CPUs which these PC had, aka multi-tasking. In general you need some structure with data describing entire state of the task (e.g. current values of i,j, if it started , if it finished, some intermeadiate data). Then you have to define, how you dispatch time between tasks, measured in "steps" - quants, and run that in a loop. Heck, I remember that TopSpeed C compiler had some library for that.

Comment: You could use a [coroutine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) that calls `co_await` often enough to "not block". If it's possible to have C++20 on ESP32.

Comment: I didn't mean to keep it secret:
https://github.com/muebau/WLED/blob/main/usermods/TetrisAI_v2/tetrisai.h#L138

This is the real function I am talking about.
I try to find the next move for the Tetris game and it takes to long and blocks the rest of the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

The general concept you're looking for is [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) or *co-operative multi-tasking*.

The idea is that functions can be suspended and resumed, so that multiple activities can be interleaved on a single thread.

It's "co-operative" because the functions need to explicitly yield (for example with `co_yield` or `co_await`) instead of being pre-empted by a scheduler like with threads.

You can always write some kind of state machine(s) to do this manually, in much the same way that we could write functor classes that manually stored their state before we had lambdas with first-class language support.

NB. For your specific use case, a state machine would need to somehow break your search space into discrete chunks (of acceptable duration) and then just process one chunk per "step". If you can manage this so that you get a reasonably good result even if you run out of time to find the best possible move, even better.

Comment: Ok this is something to read and learn. Thank you a lot.
I had the idea with the state machine and chunks too. It would be great as there would be a "good enough" option.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to [this](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/coroutines.html), it leverages C switch statements in a creative(and honestly horrifying) way to implement co-routines, in this case he uses static variables which in general might not be a good idea but I think it'll work for your use case as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will read that. It is perfect as it goes all the way from C preprocessor over C++20 native to general philosophy. Thank you again.

Comment: Omg. The linked blog post is very interesting and very horrifying at the same time :)